# Speeding up multiple conditional summations

Tags: summation, recursion, logic

I have situation where I have a matrix H, and want to build a set of ODEs dependent on the values of the eigenvalues, let me illustrate:

```
Rho[n_]:=Array[Subscript[r,#1,#2][t]&,{n,n}]
Func[lamb_]:= Which[lamb<0, g1, lamb==0, g2, lamb>0, g3]

{vals, vecs} = Eigensystem@H;
LambArray = Table[ii - jj, {ii, vals}, {jj, vals}];

SecFunc[rho_,coupop_, lambarray_,vecs_,ii_,jj_,kk_,ll_]:=Module[{Aij, Akl,diss},
Aij =vecs[[ii]].coupop.vecs[[jj]]*Outer[Times,vecs[[ii]],vecs[[jj]]];
Akl = vecs[[kk]].coupop.vecs[[ll]]*Outer[Times,vecs[[kk]],vecs[[ll]]] ;
diss = Func[lambarray[[ii,jj]]](Aij.rho.dag[Akl] + Akl.rho. ConjugateTranspose[Aij] - ConjugateTanspose[Akl].Aij.rho - rho. ConjugateTranspose[Aij].Akl);
diss]


MatBuild[rho_,coupop_,lambarray_,vecs_]:=ParallelSum[If[lambarray[[ii,jj]]==lambarray[[kk,ll]], 
SecFunc[rho, coupop, lambarray, vecs,ii,jj,kk,ll],0],
{ii,1,Length@vecs},{jj,1,Length@vecs},{kk,1,Length@vecs},{ll,1,Length@vecs}]
```

where `coupop` is an array of numbers the same dimension as `H`. `g1`, `g2` and `g3` are all real numbers, positive numbers. I want to build a set of ODEs using this function, but the actual building of the equations takes an immense amount of time, even when `H` is only an 18x18 matrix. Is there a nicer/faster way to code this?

Comment: What's `Outter` and all the other undefined symbols?

Comment: That was me misspelling `Outer[]` :).